# Drag google map behind bottom sheet on Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have scaffold bottom sheet above of google map view, my bottom sheet has a transparent part, can I drag the google map behind from transparent part of bottom sheet?

My widget tree is:

```
Scaffold
- Stack
  - Google Map
  - Other Overlay
- Bottom Sheet
```

Comment: Can you share code snippet ?

Comment: @MilanSurelia hi, I have found my own solution, I do it without bottom sheet but with widget above google map on stack

Answer (score 1):

I have found my own solution, I do it without bottom sheet but with widget above google map on stack

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).